How to display a d3-sankey chart using ReactJS?
I'm trying to create a basic sankey diagram using d3-sankey and ReactJS.
The chart is only displayed with static data from the code.
The data is displayed with both static and backend data on the console log but the chart is displayed only with static data.
If I load the data from the backend I got this error:
    Uncaught TypeError: source is undefined
    renderLinks Sankey.js:512
    renderLinks Sankey.js:506
    render Sankey.js:657

Home component
const Home = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
         fetchData();
     }, [])
    const backendDataLoading = useSelector((state) => state.chartReducer.loading);
    // Chart is not working with backendData
    const backendData = useSelector((state) => state.chartReducer.data);
    // chart works fine with staticData
    const staticData = {nodes: [...], links: [...]};

    return(<>{!backendDataLoading && backendData ? <Sankey data={backendData} width={400} height={400} /> : '...'}</>)
}

Sankey component
    export const Sankey = ({ width, height, data }: SankeyProps) => {
      // The data is displayed with both static and backend data on the console log
      console.log('data', data);
      const [data1, setData1] = useState(null);
      // const [allGroups, setAllGroups] = useState(null);
      // const [colorScale, setColorScale] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setData1(data);
        /*const allGroups = [...new Set(data.nodes.map((d) => d.index))].sort();
        const colorScale = scaleOrdinal<string>().domain(allGroups).range(COLORS);
        setAllGroups(allGroups);
        setColorScale(colorScale);*/
      }, []);
    
      // Set the sankey diagram properties
      const makeSankeyFunc = () => {
        return sankey() // TODO: find how to type the sankey() function
          .nodeAlign(sankeyCenter)
          .nodeWidth(26)
          .nodePadding(10)
          .extent([
            [MARGIN_X, MARGIN_Y],
            [width - MARGIN_X, height - MARGIN_Y],
          ])
          .nodeId((node) => node.index) // Accessor function: how to retrieve the id that defines each node. This id is then used for the source and target props of links
          .nodeAlign(sankeyCenter);
      }; // Algorithm used to decide node position
    
      const sankeyGenerator = useMemo(
        () =>
          /*{
            width,
            height,
          }*/
          makeSankeyFunc(),
        [width, height]
      );
    
      // Compute nodes and links positions
      const sankeyResult = useMemo(() => {
        if (!data) return null;
        //data.nodes[0].y0 = 0;
    
        const genned = sankeyGenerator(data);
        /*const { 0: firstNode, [genned.nodes.length - 1]: lastNode } = genned.nodes;
        const height = firstNode.y1 - firstNode.y0;
        console.log("height", height);
        firstNode.y0 = 5;
        firstNode.y1 = height;
        lastNode.y0 = 5;
        lastNode.y1 = height;*/
    
        return sankeyGenerator.update(genned);
    
        return genned;
      }, [data, sankeyGenerator]);
      const { nodes, links } = sankeyResult;
      
            //
  // Draw the nodes
  //
  const allNodes = nodes.map((node) => {
    console.log("node", node);

    return (
      <g key={node.index}>
        <rect
          height={node.y1 - node.y0}
          width={sankeyGenerator.nodeWidth()}
          x={node.x0}
          y={node.y0}
          stroke={"black"}
          fill={colorScale(node.name)}
          fillOpacity={1}
          rx={0.9}
        />
      </g>
    );
  });

  //
  // Draw the links
  //
  const allLinks = links.map((link, i) => {
    console.log("link", link);

    const linkGenerator = sankeyLinkHorizontal();
    const path = linkGenerator(link);

    return (
      <path
        key={i}
        d={path}
        stroke={colorScale(link.source.name)}
        fill="none"
        strokeOpacity={0.3}
        strokeWidth={link.width}
      />
    );
  });

  //
  // Draw the Labels
  //
  const allLabels = nodes.map((node, i) => {
    return (
      <text
        key={i}
        x={node.x0 < width / 2 ? node.x1 + 6 : node.x0 - 6}
        y={(node.y1 + node.y0) / 2}
        dy="0.35rem"
        textAnchor={node.x0 < width / 2 ? "start" : "end"}
        fontSize={12}
      >
        {node.name}
      </text>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <svg width={width} height={height}>
        {allLinks}
        {allNodes}
        {allLabels}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );

  }

